# Data structure for simulation of a NFA

Tags: python, finite-automata, nfa

I'm trying to figure out the best data structure for this, I tried a dict but seems not the better choice.

```
(0, ''): [0, 1, 3], (1, 'a'): 2, (2, ''): [2, 1, 3], (3, 'b'): 4
```

Inside the lists there are the `ε-moves`, but when I don't put them it's hard to implement the `ε-closure` function.

I'm trying to implement a algorithm like this from the Dragon's Book:
[image]

I have no idea how I can implement the `ε-closure` in a Python way.

Regex: `a*b`

[image]

Maybe a linked list? Thanks for examples.

Comment: "The best" is subjective. Please give us some more objective criteria for what you are trying to achieve. Thanks.

Comment: In order to find a good datastructure, you must first define how you will simulate the NFA, branch-by-branch, dynamic programming,...